# `Module has no exports` in npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I created a component library that I deployed internally to the company's NPM solution (basically a middleman between NPM and the client). I was able to install the library and can see the components in it but when I try to use it I get an error saying:

```
Attempted import error: 'ui-library' does not contain a default export (imported as 'SelectInput').
ERROR in ./src/views/Onboarding/OnboardingForm/OnboardingForm.js 58:41-52
export 'default' (imported as 'SelectInput') was not found in 'ui-library' (module has no exports).
```

I'm importing in my page just like you would any other component:
`import SelectInput from 'ui-library';` In the ui-library codebase, I have a root index.js exporting all of the components like so:

```
export { default as Button } from "./components/Button";
export { default as DataTable } from "./components/DataTable";
export { default as Header } from "./components/Header";
export { default as Hero } from "./components/Hero";
export { default as InfoCard } from "./components/InfoCard";
export { default as Search } from "./components/Search";
export { default as SelectInput } from "./components/SelectInput";
export { default as SideNav } from "./components/SideNav";
```

And this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ui-library",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "description": "UI Components",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://mycompanybinrepo.com/artifactory/api/npm/iot-platform-npm/"
  },
  "private": false,
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "files": [
    "lib/",
    "!lib/**/*.spec.js"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    // Commented out for SO
  },
  "scripts": {
    "buildPackage": "npm run initializePackage && rm -rf ./lib/stories && npm pack",
    "compilePackage": "npm run sass:compile && node_modules/@babel/cli/bin/babel.js src/ --out-dir lib",
    "initializePackage": "npm run compilePackage",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --no-cache --verbose",
    "sass:compile": "node_modules/sass/sass.js src/globalStyles/globalTheme.scss lib/globalStyles/globalTheme.css",
    "sass:compile:local": "node_modules/sass/sass.js src/globalStyles/globalTheme.scss src/globalStyles/globalTheme.css",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@git.company.com:platform/ui-library.git"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "env": {
      "BABEL_ENV": "production"
    }
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "modules": false,
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }
      ],
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Am I missing additional settings to be able to successfully import the components? Any advice/tips would be really appreciated.

Comment: did you ever resolve this issue? I'm seeing something similar, I'll post an answer if I find one. I also see [module has no exports on my new npm package that I publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70691154/module-has-no-exports-on-my-new-npm-package-that-i-publish) that may answer this